# How do i make the game wait on Love2D?

Tags: lua, wait, love2d

How do i make Love2D wait a couple of seconds?I tried this code

```
function love.load()
    face=love.graphics.newImage("face.png")
end

function love.draw()
     love.graphics.draw(face,400,300)
     love.timer.sleep(1)
     love.graphics.draw(face,200,600)
end
```

but then the screen turned white for a little and then the image appeared.
If someone help me,i'll be thankful

Answer (score 0):

love.timer.sleep freezes the whole program because when you run it everything stops until it is completed

[cron.lua](https://github.com/kikito/cron.lua) is great for executing actions at a certain time interval.

`local clock = cron.after(time, callback, ...)` Creates a clock that will execute callback after time passes. If additional params were provided, they are passed to callback.

An example from cron.lua's github page

```
local cron = require 'cron'

local function printMessage()
  print('Hello')
end

-- the following calls are equivalent:
local c1 = cron.after(5, printMessage)
local c2 = cron.after(5, print, 'Hello')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the [hump.timer](http://hump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/timer.html) library for this kind of functionality.

To use it, just do:

```lua
Timer.after(1, function() print("Hello, world!") end)
-- prints "Hello world!" after 1 second
```

And make sure to run update on the Timer inside your love.update function

```
function love.update(dt)
    Timer.update(dt)
end
```

Comment: Thanks,but i tried this code:

'function love.load()
    timer=require "hump.timer"
    face=love.graphics.newImage("face.png")
end

function love.update(dt)
    timer.update(dt)
end

function love.draw()
    timer.after(1,function()
        love.graphics.draw(face)
    end)
end'

but then this error happened

Error

main.lua:2:module 'hump.timer' not found

 and then some locations that i suppose the game tried to find

Comment: Have you downloaded the hump library and added it to your project's folder? Also, "hump.timer" in the require line would mean that timer.lua is inside a hump folder. So make sure that's where timer.lua is located. Otherwise you could just place the timer.lua file in the same directory as main.lua, and just use: require "timer"

Comment: Ok.where do i download it?

Comment: On their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/vrld/hump), as stated in the [docs homepage](http://hump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)